# Запись в куки посредством javascript

Tags: javascript, кэширование

Есть функция, которая устанавливает куки, в нее передаются параметры.

> - **props** Объект с дополнительными    свойствами для установки cookie:
> - **expires** Время истечения cookie. Интерпретируется по-разному, в зависимости от типа:
>
> > 1. Если число - количество секунд до истечения.
> > 2. Если объект типа Date - точная дата  истечения.
> > 3. Если expires в прошлом, то cookie будет удалено.
> > 4. Если expires отсутствует или равно 0, то cookie будет установлено как сессионное и исчезнет при закрытии браузера.
>
> - **path** Путь для cookie.
> - **domain** Домен для cookie.
> - **secure** Пересылать cookie только по защищенному соединению.

т.е по сути я могу в props передавать время или дату жизни куки, но никак не получается задать правильный синтаксис. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать, например 30 секунд

Сама функция :

```
function setCookie(name, value, props) {
    props = props || {}
    var exp = props.expires
    if (typeof exp == "number" && exp) {
        var d = new Date()
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + exp*1000)
        exp = props.expires = d
    }
    if(exp && exp.toUTCString) { props.expires = exp.toUTCString() }

    value = encodeURIComponent(value)
    var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value
    for(var propName in props){
        updatedCookie += "; " + propName
        var propValue = props[propName]
        if(propValue !== true){ updatedCookie += "=" + propValue }
    }
    document.cookie = updatedCookie

}
```

пробую

```
onclick="setCookie('hellowbox','yes','time() + 3000')"
```

так кэширует только на сессию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setCookie('test', 1, {expires: 30});
```

Только при чём тут слово "кэширование" в заголовке вопроса?

Comment: в колонке expires значение Session

Comment: И что значит этот комментарий?
Я ответил на твой вопрос - "как установить время жизни например 30 секунд"

Comment: Нашел решение - оно в моей невнимательности, к сожалению.
{expires: 30} 
ставил в кавычки